# Too-big I-beam Cursor goes outside the contenteditable div box when using placeholder

Tags: html, css

I'm using the contenteditable div to grab user's input. However, a too-big I-beam cursorr show up when I clicked it. If removing the rule :empty:before the too-big twinkle cursor problem seems to be fixed but the placeholder also disappeared. So I wondered how to make the I-beam cursor back to the normal size but still keeping the placeholder?

```
 <html>
    <div id="comment_box" contenteditable="true" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" placeholder="How do you do?"></div>

<style>

#comment_box{
    text-align: center;
  background-color: white;

  /*position:relative;*/
  border: 1px solid orange;
  /*height:60px;*/
  width: 500px;
  padding: 10px;
  color:black;
  border-radius:5px;
  /*font-size:18px;*/
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
  vertical-align: bottom;

  /*border-color:yellow;*/
}
#comment_box:focus{
  outline-style:solid;
  outline-color:orange;
  outline-width:0px;
}


[contenteditable=true]:empty:before{
  content: attr(placeholder);
  color: #aaa;
  display: block;  For Firefox 
 }

</style>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you mean the [I-beam cursor](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/i/ibeam.htm)?

Comment: Yeah, the I-beam cursor

Comment: So the mouse cursor, not the [text caret](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_navigation)? Just trying to understand what you mean so I can edit the question.

Comment: The I-beam cursor, not the text caret. The thing is the I-beam cursor goes outside of the text caret, which is unfavorable.